# some troubles in using imgur API

Tags: javascript, ajax, api, axios

I'd like to upload image with axios

```
axios.post('https://api.imgur.com/3/image' , {image : 'data:image/png;base64,' + 'base64Data' , album : 'albumID'} , {
"headers": {
"content-type": "multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW",
"Authorization": "Client-ID {MyClientID}"
}
});
```

> it fires 400 Error (Bad Request I think)

Comment: Assuming that base64Data is a variable remove the quotes from it

Comment: @charlietfl , yes = that's right

Comment: @charlietfl = I think you have something to help with

Comment: No idea what that means or if your problem is solved or not. Really not sure can add anything else without being able to see the actual response if problem still persists

Comment: @charlietfl , you don't know where's the problem ? need more details ?

Comment: is there an actual response message in the response headers or body?

Comment: I used try and catch = but it only makes error : Request failed with status code 400

Comment: Did you inspect request in browser dev tools network for any clues? have you followed their documentation fully? Auth header seems strange it's not base64 encoded. is that api cors enabled also? Have never used it so all i can do is ask many questions which is time consuming

Comment: You cannot set the boundary in a multipart/form-data ajax request

Comment: @charlietfl , yes after catching the error and displaying it : Request failed with status code 400

Comment: Oh , but I fetched these copy/paste from their documentation

Comment: @27mdmo7sn Did you inspect the request with the developer tools of your browser as suggested by @charlietfl? See https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/ for chromes dev tools.

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech , the problem should be with the passed variables , also check this https://community.imgur.com/t/some-troubles-in-using-imgur-api/58854

Comment: @27mdmo7sn You may be right, but if you are not willing to verify that the variables are sent correctly by your browser, we cannot (and won't) help you.

Comment: @PaulGeorgPodlech
I updated the question and posted it again as a new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51714560/cant-use-imgur-api-to-upload-image